# Нужна выборка из двух таблиц по условию равных идентификаторов в обоих таблицах. Но, во второй таблице может не быть строки с таким идентификатором

Tags: sql

```
Select Base.CN As Base_CN,
  NullIf(Files.CN, '') As Files_CN
From Base
  Inner Join Files On Base.CN = Files.CN
```

Такое выводит все строки, которым соответствуют заполненные строки второй таблицы. А мне бы хотелось вывести ВСЕ из первой, даже если во второй нет соответствующего CN. Выручайте!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для этого `Left join`

```
Select Base.CN As Base_CN,
  NullIf(Files.CN, '') As Files_CN
From Base
  Left Join Files On Base.CN = Files.CN
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!!